# iPython custom cell magic - store output in variable?

Tags: python, parsing, jupyter-notebook, ipython, ipython-magic

I recently discovered iPython magic functions and wrote some custom magic. I would like to use cell magic to parse strings, change them slightly and return the result.
Is there a way to store the output of my custom cell magic function in a variable?

I know you can store the output of a line magic function like this:

```python
@register_line_magic
def linemagic(line, cell=None):
    #do something
    return line

hello = %linemagic hello
print(hello)
```

Which returns:

```
>>> hello
```

In case I have larger strings, I would like to use cell magic instead:

```python
@register_cell_magic
def cellmagic(line, cell=None):
    #do something
    return cell
```

It's not possible to use `hello = %%cellmagic ...` to store the result.
Is there another way to capture the function output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use IPython's [input/output caching system](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/reference.html#output-caching-system):

Output caching:

- `_` (a single underscore): stores previous output, like Python’s default interpreter.
- `__` (two underscores): next previous.
- `___` (three underscores): next-next previous.
- `_n` (`n` being the prompt counter): the result of output
- actually, `_4`, `Out[4]` or `_oh[4]` all do the same thing

Similarly, for Input caching:

- `_i`, `_ii`, `_iii`: store previous, next previous and next-next previous inputs.
- `_i4`, `_ih[4]` and `In[4]`: the content of input `<n>` (e.g `4`)

```py
In [2]: from IPython.core.magic import register_cell_magic

In [3]: @register_cell_magic
   ...: def cellmagic(line, cell=None):
   ...:     #do something
   ...:     return cell
   ...:

In [4]: %%cellmagic
   ...: "line0"
   ...: "line1"
   ...: "line2"
   ...:
   ...:
Out[4]: '"line0"\n"line1"\n"line2"\n\n'

In [5]: _
Out[5]: '"line0"\n"line1"\n"line2"\n\n'

In [6]: _4
Out[6]: '"line0"\n"line1"\n"line2"\n\n'

In [8]: _i4
Out[8]: '%%cellmagic\n"line0"\n"line1"\n"line2"'

In [9]: var = _4

In [10]: var
Out[10]: '"line0"\n"line1"\n"line2"\n\n'
```

Comment: What's `_i4` please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I just updated the answer, now you can find out :)

Comment: Many thanks for clarifying - you already have my vote 